# Proper Field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Given a field $F$, is there a proper field extension $K$ such that any root in $K$ of a polynomial in $F[X]$ is in $F$? 
Note: I am not looking for the algebraic closure of $F$.
One candidate is the field of rational functions over $F$, but I have a problem in my argument when the numerator and denominator are the same degree.
Does anyone have a more elegant Argument than multiplying out powers of rational functions?

Comment: Such an extension can't be algebraic. I think this is your best shot considering that if I look at something like $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ I feel that it would satisfy your conditions. Maybe you can use the proof of this (if you would be able to prove it) to show this is true for any field of characteristic $0$

Comment: Suppose your numerator and denominator have the same degree. Polynomial division will give a constant plus a rational function whose numerator has degree less than that of the denominator. If this element is a root of a relevant polynomial, so is the same element less the constant. So if you can prove that case, you can prove the one you are finding difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a root of a polynomial in $F[x]$ is called being algebraic over $F$. There are extensions $K/F$ in which no element of $K\setminus F$ is algebraic over $F$. Indeed any purely transcendental extension will work (i.e. any adjunction of a collection of algebraically independent indeterminates - no matter what the cardinality of this collection). This is because any rational function satisfying an algebraic relation over $F$ would, after clearing denominators, exhibit an algebraic relation among the hypothesized algebraic independents, a contradiction.